# CakePHP 3.8 - Cookie Deletion

Tags: cakephp, cookies, settings, cakephp-3.x

I tried to set an autoLogin per Cookie, but can't delete the Cookie with the function shown in the [CakePHP Books](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cookies).

I have a Login-Function which checks for "persistence" which is the "Remember Me" Checkbox. 
If checked, create a Cookie, generate a key, assign it to the user and send it with the response:

**UsersController::login()**

```php
if ($this->request->getData('persistence')) {
  $cookie = $this->Users->createLoginCookie($user, '+1 Month');

  $this->response = $this->response->withCookie($cookie
  );
}

return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
```

**UsersTable::createLoginCookie();**

```php
public function createLoginCookie($user, $expiry){
  $key = Text::uuid();
  $user = $this->findByEmail($user['email'])->first();
  $user->persistence_key = $key;
  $this->save($user);

  $cookie = new Cookie(
    'persistence_key', $key,
    new DateTime($expiry),
    '',
    '',
    false,
    false
  );
   return $cookie;
}
```

And I want the Cookie to be deleted, if the user is manually logging out:

**UsersController::logout()**

```php
if ($cookie = $this->request->getCookie('persistence_key')) {
  $this->response = $this->response->withExpiredCookie($cookie);
}
$this->Flash->success('You have been logged out.');
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
```

Sadly the Cookie won't be removed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is it getting to the `withExpiredCookie` call, or is that condition failing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `$cookie = $this->request->getCookie('persistence_key')` returns the cookie value, not the cookie itself. So you pass the cookie value to the `withExpiredCookie()` method instead of the cookie name. And anyway, passing the cookie name is now deprecated.

Something like this should work:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('persistence_key');
$this->response = $this->response->withExpiredCookie($cookie);
```

Please note that the cookie path must also correspond to how you create your cookie. As I have many CakePHP application on localhost, I tend to specifiy the cookie path when I create cookies:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('my-cookie');
$cookie = $cookie->withPath(Router::url('/'));
```

So I have to destruct them like this:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('my-cookie');
$cookie = $cookie->withPath(Router::url('/'));
$this->response = $this->response->withExpiredCookie($cookie);
```

Comment: One could retrieve the cookie object from the cookie collection, like `$this->request->getCookieCollection()->get('persistence_key')`.